# Determine whether a focused window has an active caret

Tags: delphi, winapi, controls, caret, delphi-6

Following `_isEdit` function detects whether input could be applied to the currently focused control:

```
class function TSpeedInput._getFocusedControlClassName(): WideString;
var
  lpClassName: array[0..1000] of WideChar;
begin
  FillChar(lpClassName, SizeOf(lpClassName), 0);
  Windows.GetClassNameW(GetFocus(), PWideChar(@lpClassName), 999);
  Result := lpClassName;
end;

class function TSpeedInput._isEdit(): Boolean;
const
  CNAMES: array[0..3] of string = ('TEdit', 'TMemo', 'TTntMemo.UnicodeClass',
    'TTntEdit.UnicodeClass');
var
  cn: WideString;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  cn := _getFocusedControlClassName();
  for i := Low(CNAMES) to High(CNAMES) do
    if cn = CNAMES[i] then begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  //MessageBoxW(0, PWideChar(cn), nil, 0);
end;
```

What I don't like about it is the hard coding of the class name list. Could it be detected that a currently focused window belongs to the editors family or, better to say, that it has an active caret? (in order that `_isEdit` returns `False` for a **WhateverItIsControl** that is in read-only mode).

Comment: Look  at: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34520/Getting-Caret-Position-Inside-Any-Application

Comment: A readonly control can show the caret. Indeed it generally does so, so that you can copy text.

Comment: Anyway, you can try hiding the caret. If it succeeds show it again and note that there was a caret showing.

Answer (score 2):

If the controls you are interested in are on a specific form *and are owned by that form* (and are standard Delphi controls) you could use the following:

```
function TFormML2.FocusIsEdit: boolean;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  Result := FALSE;
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Components[ i ] is TCustomEdit then
    begin
      if (Components[ i ] as TCustomEdit).Focused and not (Components[ i ] as TCustomEdit).ReadOnly  then
      begin
        Result := TRUE;
        break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If you know the form and can pass it as a parameter, you could do something similar.

TCustomEdit is the ancestor of all edit boxes, memos, etc.

Comment: A few notes: (1) This will only find controls that are *owned* by `TFormML2`. This form might very well contain controls not owned by it. (2) Isn't it easier to use the `FindControl` function? (3) Not all edit controls derive from `TCustomEdit`. For instance, my own `TTextEditor` derives from `TCustomControl`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks for your comments. I was aware this might not be quite what the OP wants, but then again it might be. He does, for example, specifically ask to know if it is ReadOnly. But I agree, it i. s only all Delphi VCL native controls that are derived from TCustomEdit. I thought I had mentioned that the form must own the controls but on reading back I see that I did not. I will edit..

Comment: The OP uses `Application.OnMessage` so that an edit control could be in any form. All that I have is a handle.

Answer (score 2):

If the `Handle` of the control is allocated, you can use this hack:

```
function IsEdit(AControl: TWinControl): boolean;
begin
    if AControl.HandleAllocated then
    begin
        Result := SendMessage(AControl.Handle, EM_SETREADONLY,
            WPARAM(Ord(AControl.Enabled)), 0) <> 0;
    end
    else
    begin
        Result := AControl is TCustomEdit;
    end;
end;
```